# Select the id of every largest value in table

Tags: mysql

How select the id of every largest value in my table?

[image]

expected output:

[image]

Comment: *every largest* is confusing. Please provide more detail/explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT distinct id as 1st
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE 1st =(select max(1st)
                FROM YourTable))
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT distinct id as 2nd
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE 2nd =(select max(2nd)
                FROM YourTable))
ON(1=1)
```

This will only work in case there is 1 MAX value in each column.

Next time you ask something, please make some attempts of your own to solve it.

Comment: Yes Sir. and Thank you.

Comment: Sir it's returning a wrong value. its returning the 4 even if there's an higher value which is 12 in this query "select max(1st) FROM test"

Comment: What output do you get according to the input you gave us? The query is fine. @oo7

Comment: My expected output is 3,7 Sir. The query's output is 3,3 Sir.

Comment: Sir it's not recognizing the double digit number.

Comment: Tnx Sir. a salute for you.